# Jsoup adds whitespaces to my code

Tags: android, jsoup

My problem is that jsoup destroys my html code. I am downloading website from url, change it a little and displaying it in WebView.

Jsoup adding formating to code and it causing problems:

**Before**
html: http://jsfiddle.net/zr3xtus9/

```
<div class="ctr-element"><div class="ctr-content" style="z-index: 100; margin: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px; visibility: visible; position: relative;"><div class="ctr-textWrapper" style="text-align: center; line-height: 1; font-size: 124px;" spellcheck="false"><span style="font-size: 124px; color: rgb(245, 230, 93); font-family: capture_it_2;" id="object13textContainer0">&nbsp;P</span><span style="font-size: 124px; color: rgb(245, 230, 93); font-family: capture_it_2;" id="object13textContainer1">arty</span></div></div></div>
```

**After**
html: http://jsfiddle.net/5kv47sny/

```
 <div class="ctr-element">
  <div class="ctr-content" style="z-index: 100; margin: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px; visibility: visible; position: relative;">
   <div class="ctr-textWrapper" style="text-align: center; line-height: 1; font-size: 124px;" spellcheck="false">
    <span style="font-size: 124px; color: rgb(245, 230, 93); font-family: capture_it_2;" id="object13textContainer0" onclick="javscript:changeText('object13textContainer0')">&nbsp;P</span>
    <span style="font-size: 124px; color: rgb(245, 230, 93); font-family: capture_it_2;" id="object13textContainer1" onclick="javscript:changeText('object13textContainer1')">arty</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

As you can see jsoup adds extra whitespaces as text indent. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution is very easy. To disable text indent I used this code before printing html:

```
doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
```

Here is documentation: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.OutputSettings.html#prettyPrint(boolean)

Comment: You should mark your own answer as "Answer" for people to see how it works.